# Creating scripts for obtaining data from a text file

Tags: awk

I have a text file named stat.txt which contains lines each in the format

`<User Name>-<IP>-<File Name>-<Size>`. Each line contains a user name,an IP address,a file name and a download file size.I need to create a script userstat.awk which allows the following data to be obtained when the specific command is written:

userstat.awk u -will list all files
userstat.awk total -will list total size of all files

So far,I have tried to list all the files for a user using default commands but I can't do it using these commands.

Comment: Could you give us a sample input file and your expected output? That would be nice.

Comment: On the first glance, it looks easy because you may change the column separator in awk. In this case, `awk -F -` could be used. But this will fail if `<User Name>` or `<File Name>` contains itself a '-'. If `<` and `>` are physical parts of the pattern I would use a regular expression to separate the fields. Please, provide sample input and expected output as already suggested...

Comment: Maybe you could add some sample data. Post your code if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given stat.txt:

```
user-1.1.1.1-file.jpg-20
root-1.1.1.1-file.jpg-20
user-1.1.1.1-img.jpg-20
root-1.1.1.1-thing.jpg-20
```

You could use the command *(improved by @ClasesWikner)*:

```
awk -F- '{print $3; s+=$4}END {print "total: " s}' stat.txt
```

To output:

```
file.jpg
file.jpg
img.jpg
thing.jpg
total: 80
```

As mentioned by @Scheff this will not work when usernames or file names contain a `-`.

Comment: But why not print it in one go?
awk -F- '{print $3; s+=$4}END {print "total: " s}' stat.txt